# Find the power of $P$ in relation the center circumference $O$ below.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the acute triangle $ABC$ of orthocenter $H$ and circumcenter $O$, the
height $AP$. If the distance from $O$ to $AC$ is $2$ and $PH = 1$; calculate the power of $P$ in relation the center circumference $O$.(Answer:$ -5$)

My progress:
[image]

Points inside the circle have negative power;

$P(P) = d^2 - R^2 = PO^2-AO^2 = r^2 - R^2\\
\triangle AOD: R^2 = 4+AD^2\\
 ADE \sim \triangle APC \implies \frac{DE}{CP} = \frac{AD}{AH+1}=\frac{AE}{2AD}
\\BH=2OD (property)= 2.2=4\\
\triangle BPH: 4^2 = BP^2+1^2 \therefore BP = \sqrt15\\
\triangle APC \sim \triangle BPH \implies: \frac{PC}{1}=\frac{2AD}{4}=\frac{AH+1}{\sqrt{15}} \implies AD = 2PC\\
\therefore AE = 4DE$

???...

Comment: Please note that $BH = 2 OD = 4$. You should try and make use of it.

Comment: Is the question typed correctly? If P and D are on same sides, then power of P can be shown to be $-5$.

Comment: @MyMolecules  yes...it is correct and the answer is exactly this $-5$

Comment: @petaarantes No I don't think you would get $-5$ for the given question.

Comment: So there must be some error in the book's statement

Comment: @MathLover I had understood that MyMolecule  said that it could be shown that the power would be -5

Comment: Try with the hint I gave above and see what you get.

Comment: @MathLover  With your hint I developed some more relationships in my progress but something is still missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ - 5$ is not the correct answer.

Note that $BH = 2 OD = 4$ and hence $BP = \sqrt{15}$

We then use the fact that $\triangle ACP \sim \triangle BHP$

$ \displaystyle \implies AC = \frac{4}{\sqrt{15}} (AH+1), ~ PC = \frac{1}{\sqrt{15}} (AH+1)$

If $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$, $ \displaystyle CM = \frac {\sqrt{15} + PC}{2}$

$ \displaystyle PM = CM - PC = \frac {\sqrt{15} - PC}{2} = \frac{14 - AH}{2 \sqrt{15}}$

Power of point $P$ with respect to the circumcenter $O = OP^2 - OA^2$,

$ \displaystyle = OM^2 + PM^2 - (AD^2 + 4)$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{AH^2}{4} + \frac{(14-AH)^2}{60} - \frac{AC^2}{4} - 4$

$ \displaystyle = \frac{AH^2}{4} + \frac{(14-AH)^2}{60} - \frac{4 (AH+1)^2}{15} - 4 = - AH - 1$

So it depends on $AH$ and unless $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles with $\angle A = \angle B$, the answer cannot be $ - 5$.

Comment: Anyway there is no solution as we don't have the AH value ??

Comment: There is the alternative in the book of being -4 as the answer ... by geogebra we have 4.09 as the solution

Comment: @petaarantes The solution is $( - AH - 1)$. There is no one value. I have also clearly written when it can be $-5$ and when it cannot be. There is some typo in the problem. Also you are not correct when you say geogebra gives $4.09$. I can draw many counter examples by changing value of $AH$. In your diagram. you may have $AH \approx 3$ and that is why you got $4.09$. I just drew a diagram where power of point of $P$ wrt $O$ is $ \approx 10$ because $AH = 9$.

Comment: Understood, thanks..You said that if the triangle were isosceles there would be a solution... could you demonstrate?.

Comment: @petaarantes because then $AH = BH = 4$, right?